# nodeJS util.format passing an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am using util.format to format a string like this:

```
util.format('My name is %s %s', ['John', 'Smith']);
```

The fact that the second parameter is an array: `['John', 'Smith']`, prevents my code from replacing the second %s. But i need it to be an array because I don't know the exact number of the arguments that the string might have.

Do you have any solution to my problem?
Thank's in advance.

EDIT:
The string that contains the placeholders is not a predefined static string. I read it from a file so the placeholders might be anywhere in the string. For the same reason I also don't know the number of placeholders.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<strike>If you don't know how many variables are in that array, how do you know how many placeholders to define in your string ?</strike>

I'd suggest you only use one placeholder and just `.join()` the array, like

```
util.format('My name is %s', ['John', 'Smith'].join(' '));
```

---

**Update**

I guess I got you wrong there, you can make usage of JavaScripts `Function.prototype.apply` to pass in arguments to a function from an Array source. This could look like

```
util.format.apply(util,['My name is %s %s','John', 'Smith']);
```

Of course you would need to `.unshift()` your placeholder string into that array aswell beforehand.

Comment: The string that contains the placeholders is not a predefined static string. I read it from a file so the placeholders might be anywhere in the string. For the same reason i don't know the number of placeholders too.

Comment: @Bobos Updated. Hope that helps.

Comment: Great answer! Thank's! It seems that I need to better learn javascript ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do a for-each loop for every string object in table and replace every time one %s. (for example ['John', 'Smith'] has 2 strings)