# JavaScript Stringformat with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string-formatting

I'm using [stringformat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stringformat) library to format strings in node.js.

```
var stringFormat = require('stringformat');
stringFormat.extendString();
```

I'm trying to pass along an array of parameters instead inline, like this:

```
var formatted = '{0}{1}'.format(params);
```

Instead of :

```
var formatted = '{0}{1}'.format(params[0], params[1]);
```

But the library doesn't support this.

I've followed this question: [nodejs-util-format-passing-an-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652341/nodejs-util-format-passing-an-array)
And tried this:

```
params.unshift('{0}{1}');
String.prototype.format.apply(String.prototype, params);
```

And also:

```
var i = -1;
'{0}{1}...'.format(function() {
    i++;
    return params[0];
});
```

And none of them worked as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: may be you can try `var formatted = '{0}{1}'.format(...params);`

Comment: What's the `...` ?

Comment: It's the ES6 functionality the spread operator. It's ideal for this case.

Answer (score 1):

you can write your own format extension like this:

```
String.prototype.myFormatString = function(_array){
    var s = _array[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < _array.length - 1; i++) {       
         var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");             
         s = s.replace(reg, _array[i + 1]);
    }
    return s;
}
```

and call it in your code:

```
var formatted = '{0}{1}'.myFormatString(params);
```

hope that helps.

Comment: `s.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]);` should be `s.replace(reg, Array[i + 1]);`

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't want to use the spread operator as i have mentioned in the comment you can also do something like this in ES5;

```
function formatWithArray(str,arr){
var a = arr[0],
    b = arr[1],
    c = arr[2],
    d = arr[3];
return str.format(a,b,c,d);
}
var formatted = formatWithArray('{0}{1}',params);
```

Should work fine up to 4 parameters though in your particular case the last two (c and d) will be undefined. I hope the stringFormat library won't bother with excess parameters.